# Moscapsule in Swift 3, user disconnected sporadically and reconnected again

Tags: swift, mqtt

I have an iPhone application that uses [Moscapsule](https://github.com/flightonary/Moscapsule) in order to establish MQTT connection to a Mosquitto broker (`mosquitto version 1.4.4`).

I create the connection like this:

```
mqttConfig = MQTTConfig(clientId: "iphone7_UI", host:"x.x..x.x", keepAlive:9999)
```

Other than the above I am basically relying on the library to keep the connection up and running and properly sub/publish MQTT messages.

The application mostly **publishes** messages and so far I have not had any issues with publications. Recently I added a feature where it is required for the application to **subscribe** to a topic and this is where I am getting issues.

The application successfully subscribes to the topic and receives messages properly in the beginning but then after a while (random amount of time, a couple of minutes usually) I can see at the mosquitto printouts that the iphone client disconnects and then reconnects and when that happens it no longer receives any MQTT messages (it can still publish properly).

What could be the reason why the application (probably Moscapsule library that I am using) decides to discard the old connection and create a new one? any ideas?

Comment: Is the application always in the foreground when it disconnects?

Comment: @hardillb yes, allways in foreground